# How to assign value to custom field on AddItem

Tags: c#, list, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have an custom field written in C#. The custom field inherits from SPFieldText. Everything work well, until I want to add data into an SPList and assign value over PowerShell.

My PS code:

```
...
$newItem = $spList.AddItem() 
...
$newItem["customField"] = $value --> Error

$newItem.update()

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
+                             $newItem["customField"] = $value
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException
```

All other (native) column types work well, but I can´t assign to custom field type. I also checked if the column is present. It is.

```
$newItem.Fields.ContainsField["customField"] returns True.
```

Then I checked the XMLScheme and my custom inherited field is also there.

Could please somebody suggest an option, how to handle this - assign value to custom fields?

Comment: Are you really needing a custom field **type**, or do you just need like a NoteProperty that you can assign a value to?

Comment: Yes. I really need it.

Comment: Can you include the code where you define $SPList (web address can be bogus of coarse), and where you define your custom type, and then add the custom typed field to the list please?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was my custom field. It throw an exception. Thanks anyone.